# Excel Match & TextJoin Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, textjoin

I am attempting to pull multiple results into one cell. Before this happens, I want to crosscheck the date to make sure it is pulling the correct figures rather than all in the referenced cell.

This is where I'm up to.

`=IF(MATCH(1,(Tariff!$A$2:$A$100000=C18)*(Tariff!$D$2:$D$100000=MONTH($P$5))*(Tariff!$E$2:$E$100000=YEAR($P$5))),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(Tariff!$A$2:$A$10000=C18,Tariff!$B$2:$B$10000,"")))`

It is finding all the matching text in `C18` from the alternative sheet. However, it is not checking the date correctly against the month/year part of the formula.

I'm hoping it to pull 2 results on the same date in `P5` however it is just matching all that are the same as `C18`.

Comment: Do the date checking inside the textjoin. It may be faster to use filter inside textjoin if you have Office 365: (untested:) `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(Tariff!$B$2:$B$10000,(Tariff!$A$2:$A$100000=C18)*(Tariff!$D$2:$D$100000=MONTH($P$5)*(Tariff!$E$2:$E$100000=YEAR($P$5),""))`

Comment: For readability, I believe that for boolean variables `v1 AND v2 AND v3` is clearer than `v1 * v2 * v3`.